# How do I edit file permissions?

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter-notebook, file-permissions

I'm very new to all of this. I am using Windows 10, with Ubuntu, and Jupyter. I'm trying to get Disco Diffusion AI running per this [guide](https://github.com/MohamadZeina/Disco_Diffusion_Local). I have gotten to the point where I've installed Ubuntu, used the Anaconda addons, and opened up the .ipynb files in Jupyter.

When I open these files, however, they are listed as read only.
[File title with read only marker visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJB4m.png)

I run the first command and it correctly identifies my GPUs. But when I run the second command, I get this error.

```
Google Colab not detected.
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
PermissionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [2], in <cell line: 37>()
     34         print(f'filepath {filepath} exists.')
     36 initDirPath = f'{root_path}/init_images'
---> 37 createPath(initDirPath)
     38 outDirPath = f'{root_path}/images_out'
     39 createPath(outDirPath)

Input In [2], in createPath(filepath)
     29 def createPath(filepath):
     30     if path.exists(filepath) == False:
---> 31         os.makedirs(filepath)
     32         print(f'Made {filepath}')
     33     else:

File ~/anaconda3/envs/pytorch_110/lib/python3.9/os.py:225, in makedirs(name, mode, exist_ok)
    223         return
    224 try:
--> 225     mkdir(name, mode)
    226 except OSError:
    227     # Cannot rely on checking for EEXIST, since the operating system
    228     # could give priority to other errors like EACCES or EROFS
    229     if not exist_ok or not path.isdir(name):

PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './init_images'
```

I don't know how to change permissions from read-only. When I open the Ubuntu folders in Windows File Explorer, I don't have the option to edit their permissions when I right-click. I am running Ubuntu as an administrator. I have looked around and saw someone who said they extracted the disco diffusion zip file within Ubuntu, however, I don't know how to do that either.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your permission using command below at Ubuntu terminal. (Don't forget to type in your username)

```
sudo chown -R YourUsername .
```